# Prepared Statements в Java , ошибка в синтаксисе!

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Проблема в написании правильно строки с prepared statementom..

Где тут синтаксическая ошибка ?

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER_NAME,PASSWORD);

         String checkingUser = "SELECT nick_name FROM users WHERE nick_name=? AND password=? AND users.email=?";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(checkingUser);
        System.out.println("Before 1");
        preparedStatement.setString(1,loginData[0]);
        System.out.println("Before 2");
        preparedStatement.setString(2,loginData[1]);
        System.out.println("Before 3");
        preparedStatement.setString(3,loginData[2]);
        preparedStatement.execute();

  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
  You have an   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near '?, password=?, users.email=?' at line 1

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'? AND password=? AND users.email=?' at line 1 // перезагрузил сервак, получил данную ошибку. Что тут нетак не понимаю.. 

 Пример кода в другой части програмы, который работает. 
 String e = "UPDATE coupon SET  start_date = ? , end_date = ? , amount = ? ,  price = ? , image = ?   WHERE id = ?";
```

Проблема с AND ??

```
SELECT nick_name FROM users WHERE nick_name="****" AND password="*****" AND users.email="******";
```

Данная конструкция работает при обычном запросе к базе данных. Но не с Prepared Statement.

Получаю предупреждения от IDEA  `SQL Dialect is not configured!` 
Что и как мне настроить ?

Comment: А что такое `users.email` и почему оно не просто `email`?

Comment: SELECT nick_name FROM users WHERE nick_name="***" AND password="***" AND users.email="***"; Это то что сгенерировала IDEA в DATABASE, если работать напрямую с MySql то с таким запросом нет проблем. Как только использую в стринге с припер стейтментом получаю ошибку в синтаксисие.

Comment: Я не понимаю как получается, что у вас в запросе стоят AND, а когда MySQL ругается на ошибку он пишет что там стоят запятые

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю...

Comment: Насколько понимаю, ошибка с биндингом. Я никогда не работал с PS напрямую, но, возможно, там либо отсчет ведется с нуля, либо для ненумерованных/неименованных параметров биндинг производится по-другому.

Comment: Etki - вот бы както понять тебя, чтобы знать что искать дальше ))

Comment: в запросе, сделайте знаки вопроса внутри скобок `SELECT nick_name FROM users WHERE (nick_name= ?) AND (password=?) AND (users.email=?)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
preparedStatement.executeQuery()
```

вместо:

```
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Так посмотрите, какой запрос preparedStatement строит. Попробуйте для локализации ошибки все подстановочные переменные заменить литералами.