# Правильное использование Prepared statements в java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, preparedstatement

[Мой предыдущий пост!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574230/prepared-statements-%D0%B2-java-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5), после чего я поменял код, привожу пример:

```
  protected static boolean postDatabase(String [] loginData, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    try {

        output = response.getWriter();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER_NAME,PASSWORD);

        String checkingUser = "SELECT nick_name,email,password FROM users WHERE nick_name = ?";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(checkingUser);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,loginData[0]);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(checkingUser);

        int passwordColumn = resultSet.findColumn("password");

        if(resultSet.getString(passwordColumn).equals(loginData[1])) {

            int emailColumn = resultSet.findColumn("email");

            if(resultSet.getString(emailColumn).equals(loginData[2])){
                return  true;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioError) {
        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(ioError.toString(),response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException notFound) {
        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(notFound.toString(),response);
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(sql.toString(),response);
    }finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException sql) {
            ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(sql.toString(),response);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

> > com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Нo данный код ниже работает:

```
protected void postDataBase(User user, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    try {

        output = response.getWriter();

        System.out.print(user);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER_NAME,PASSWORD);

        String creatingUser = "INSERT INTO coupon_system.users(nick_name, first_name, last_name, password, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        String creatingUserRole = "INSERT INTO roles (rol, nickname) VALUES (?,?)";

        PreparedStatement createUser = connection.prepareStatement(creatingUser);
        createUser.setString(1,user.getNickName());
        createUser.setString(2,user.getFirstName());
        createUser.setString(3,user.getLastName());
        createUser.setString(4,user.getPassword());
        createUser.setString(5,user.getEmail());
        createUser.execute();

        PreparedStatement createRole = connection.prepareStatement(creatingUserRole);
        createRole.setString(1,user.getCustomerType());
        createRole.setString(2,user.getNickName());
        createRole.execute();

        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse("Success",response);

    } catch (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException duplicate){

        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(duplicate.toString(),response);

    }catch (ClassNotFoundException notFound){

        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(notFound.toString(),response);
    }
    catch (SQLException sql){

        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(sql.toString(),response);
    }catch (IOException io){

        ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(io.toString(),response);
    } finally {

        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException sql) {

            ResponseDataHandler.ToJSONresponse(sql.toString(),response);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Не могу понять ошибку, которую получаю.. Если бы была связь о проблеме с версией MySQL Server на моём ПК, то при регистрации данная конструкция тоже должна была не работать.. Если кто сталкивался с таким - буду рад помощи!

Comment: Может у вас пробелы лишние вокруг равно перед вопросом?

Comment: Чего ? Вы о чём ?

Comment: `nick_name = ?` что если отсюда все пробелы убрать? чтобы стало `nick_name=?`

Comment: String checkingUser = "SELECT nick_name,email,password FROM users WHERE nick_name=?";  - убрал таким образом, получаю ту же ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно en-so  вам надо запускать запрос без аргументов

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24692705/3212712

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

Comment: Действительно. Зачем его препарировать, если в итоге запускаете пусть такою же, но на самом деле совсем другой запрос.